# Reordering database after certain time period without harming dependencies in django

Tags: mysql, django, database

I'm wondering if there is any way to reorder whole database after a month or weeks in maintenance such that if my database has 10000+ of records and some in between records are deleted for example:

```
records: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
after deleting:1,2,5,8,9
after reordering:1,2,3,4,5
```

I'm using mysql as backend, and after reordering the dependencies between models must be retained such as `ForeignKey`, `ManyToManyField`

Comment: There is no sensible reason for wanting to do this

Comment: I don't know much about database management but if after certain time if we reorder the database then it can give us better performance while searching database or database manipulations

Comment: Any possible benefit would be to the detriment of data integrity. The gains would be negligible. The losses could be disastrous.